# CUSTOM HELP how i can upload file and show pic in my file

Tags: search, custom, help, collection

when i upload word document in site collections help but if  my file have picture do not show my pic when i  click in help( ? ) how i can show my  pic
 and my search box in help do not work.its  disable
 help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please doublecheck you followed this steps to add images

1. Upload and check in the images that you want to include in the Help article to the appropriate categories you created in your Help library.
2. Open a new Word document, and type the text that you want to appear in your Help article.
3. In the Help library, navigate to the image you uploaded, right-click it, and then click Copy Shortcut.
4. In Word, click the Insert tab, and then click Picture.
5. In the File Name box, paste the URL you copied in step 3.
6. Click the drop-down arrow next to the Insert button, and then click Link to File.

Please have a look at this step-by-step guide to get a full overview of all steps to be done to get custom help work.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-custom-Help-to-a-site-collection-ac763916-0225-4065-a63a-35f3d1c4e22b?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1

Comment: Please don’t add just a link as answer to a question. If the link breaks, the answer you provided will not be useful for future visitors. Provide an answer of your own and use the link as [reference](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). If needed, you can block quote the content from your link. More information is found in our help center, especially [How do I write a good answer](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)